# How Quote Works in Magento 2 and Data is inserted into Quote and Quote Item Table?

Tags: quote, quoteitem, magento2.4.4, sales-quote

I want to know how Quote system works and how data is inserted into quote tables and how api retrieves data.Everything about quote by pure coding point of view i know that quote is cart object later on it is converted into order Any reference link to blog,article,book or direct answer would be appreciated thanks advance.

Comment: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/module-reference/module-quote/

https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/class_magento_1_1_quote_1_1_model_1_1_quote.html

Comment: Very Helpful thank you @NileshDubey

Comment: Fount it helpful thank you @NileshDubey